# How to change word spacing of figure captions?

Tags: captions

[image]

Why is this weird spacing in the captions happening? How can I fix it? Here's the code I'm using:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
\minipage{0.28\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2dc.jpg}
  \caption{2D Chrysanthemum}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.28\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2dc2.jpg}
  \caption{2.5D Chrysanthemum}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.28\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chrys.jpg}
  \caption{Chrysanthemum with multuple symmetry channels}
\endminipage
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Normally, loading `caption` and `ragged2e`, and adding `\captionsetup{lustification=RaggedRight}` should do the trick.

Comment: what do you mean by loading caption and ragged2e? i'm very new to latex!

Comment: The caption package allows one to (more easily) modify the formatting of captions.  The ragget2e package defines RaggedRight (as opposed to the normal raggedright).  In your case, the simplest solution is to add a hypen into Chrysanthemum.  (Not sure why it isn't working automatically.)

Comment: Somewhere between `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` (the "preamble"), type `\usepackage{caption}` and `\usepackage{ragged2e}`: [overleaf guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Creating_a_document_in_LaTeX#The_preamble_of_a_document)

Comment: Yes. @JohnKormylo's suggestion should also work, but you have to find the insertion point of `\-`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you provide the instruction

```
\hyphenation{chry-san-the-mum}
```

in the preamble. (By default, TeX will *not* hyphenate 'chrysanthemum' between 'chry' and 'san'.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hyphenation{chry-san-the-mum}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.28\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2dc.jpg}
  \caption{2D Chrysanthemum}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.28\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2dc2.jpg}
  \caption{2.5D Chrysanthemum}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.28\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chrys.jpg}
  \caption{Chrysanthemum with multuple symmetry channels}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Of course, you can combine the preceding approach with the suggestion made by @Bernard and others in the comments, viz., to insert the instructions

```
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e}
\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight}
```

in the preamble. Combining both approaches (and fixing a typo in one of the captions...) creates the following output:

[image]